# Unable to update from Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I am unable to update from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Getting below info for lsb release and do upgrade command -

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal


do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrade
```

What shall I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 22.04 is not a development release, and because 24.04 has not been released yet, simply run the following commands instead.

First, make sure everything is up to date:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

and then do release upgrade without the -d option:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

---

Also, if you edited `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` to set `Prompt=normal` then you should set it back to `Prompt=lts` before trying again.

Comment: `apt dist-upgrade` is essentially the same as `apt full-upgrade` but in any case and unless you have some packages intentionally held back or pinned, this should apply all available updates before the upgrade.